# How can I remove the cap from my chlorine feeder?

Tags: pool

Chlorine feeder cap broke while attempting to remove it. Pool had been shut off for 2 weeks. It feels like there is a vacuum inside the feeder. I used a 2x4 across the cap fins for leverage, but one fin broke off. I also broke the PVC fittings connected to the feeder. Cap didn't come off yet. How do I get rid of the suction? I tried everything I read on this post so far.

Comment: Post some pics please. If you broke PVC fittings leading to this unit, and the pump equipment is shut down completely, then you could not have a vacuum.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I fix a chlorine feeder that's nearly impossible to open?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/7312/how-do-i-fix-a-chlorine-feeder-thats-nearly-impossible-to-open)

Answer (score 1):

I found one answer to my own question today. Although I still don't know why the cap was so tight I managed to remove it. At first I used a 2x4 across the cap top and a rubber strap wrench to hold the feeder from turning. But I broke all 4 cap fins plus the pvc fittings which were connected to the feeder.  Then I removed the feeder and placed it in a vise on my work bench. That made me nervous as I was trying not to crack the feeder body. But the cap came off with a strap wrench, finally.  I am still curious to know why the cap was so tight. It felt like a vacuum even after I loosed a bleeder on top of my cartridge filter, I loosened the basket lid on my pool pump, and I removed the broken pvc fittings and any plug I could find on the feeder. The cap was always tight for 12 years but never like this time. Go figure.

Comment: I'd like to thank Jimmy Fix it for his post. Yes, I agree that I should not have a vacuum with all the stuff I disconnected. So, what would make the cap more stubborn this time than the last 12 years?